# Sort an array of characters

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

Here is an interview question I've had.

Input: A string of characters (ASCII), could be a sentence. There can dups.
Output: Sorted in order of ASCII values

Expected complexity: Linear time and constant additional space

My thought was to do a type of bucket sort where you have a size 256 array and then use that, but if you have duplicates then how would handle that? Would this be considered constant space? I guess it would because you'd only ever use a 256 size array, and that it wouldn't grow with the size of the input.

Don't want the specific code as I'd like to do that myself, but any hints would be helpful!

Comment: Think what the value of the array should be. (And you only need the size to be 128 for ASCII...)

Comment: Oh ok I see. The index position would be the character and the value would be the count. Thanks!

Comment: It will be a counting sort. Linear time with 128 size array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is [counting sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/).

You would have an array of size 128 size and all values are initialized to 0. Use the ascii value of a character to index into the array and then increment the array value.

The sorted sequence would be  produced just by traversing the array of size 128, where you only print the character of ascii value i if array[i] is non-zero and the value gives the frequency of the character to be printed.

You are right this is constant size O(1) and linear time O(N) algorithm.

Comment: Note that for ASCII the array size only needs to be 128, not 256. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding.

Comment: @JonSkeet We do have extended size ascii character set.Right. But thats not the point. anyway.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" isn't a specific encoding, and is generally an unhelpful term in my experience. It would be better to edit your answer to avoid giving the impression that ASCII has 256 characters - there are far too many places on the net propagating that fallacy already.